# What's ApiController attribute good for precisely (especially outside of development)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I've seen the attribute `[ApiController]` being suggested in the template. I gto curious what's it good for because, as far I understand, my API is already recognized as an API due to `[Route(...)]` attribute. So I've checked [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apicontrollerattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) telling me that it provides me with

> features and behavior targeted at improving the developer experience for building APIs

Well... What exactly are those features (haven't missed them previously so I'm curious what issue that attribute resolves).

Also, I wonder if there's a point to have that attribute if we're outside the context of development, i.e. does it make any difference to add it to a pre-existing project that already runs in the production needing no maintenance.

Comment: https://www.strathweb.com/2018/02/exploring-the-apicontrollerattribute-and-its-features-for-asp-net-core-mvc-2-1/

Comment: [Official MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#annotation-with-apicontroller-attribute)